# How to deploy my project to Maven's Central Repository when it's already in Sonatype repository

Tags: maven, sonatype

I have followed the guide of http://jroller.com/holy/entry/releasing_a_project_to_maven, and deployed my project into sonatype release repository successfully.

You can see my project in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases.

[image]

But I still can't find my project in Maven's Central Repository. And not everyone's nexus has config sonatype release repo , but I'm very sure everyone has Maven central repository.

So who can tell me how to let Maven central repo collect my project?
What should I need to do now?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read and follow step 6 in the description you link to:

> When the artifacts are in the release repository, add a comment to the
>   original ticket asking for them to be published to Maven Central. For
>   the first time they need to do it manually but since that on it will
>   be synchronized automatically every hour